# Adding custom tick marks to matplotlib color bar

Tags: matplotlib

I am trying to add a custom tick mark (or a pointer, such as the green triangle in the figure below) to a matplotlib color bar, in order to highlight a specific level (significance in this case). I came up with the following, but the positions (of both the pointer and the associated text) needs to be modified when the figure is resized. I couldn't figure out a more straigthforward way of doing this.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
pvalues=np.array([[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],[0.03225688,np.nan,np.nan],[0.9160038 , 0.3538501 ,np.nan]])
labels=[0,1,2]
significance_threshold=0.05
plt.imshow(-np.log10(pvalues),cmap='YlOrRd_r',vmin=0,vmax=10)
plt.xticks(labels)
plt.yticks(labels)
plt.title(r'$-log_{10}(pvalues)$')
#hashing cells of non significant pvalues
for i in labels:
    for j in labels:
        if(i>j):
            if(pvalues[i,j]>0.05):
                plt.gca().add_patch(mpl.patches.Rectangle((j-.5, i-.5), 1, 1,color='cyan', hatch='///',fill=False, snap=True))
                
cb=plt.colorbar()
cb.ax.scatter([31], [-np.log10(significance_threshold)], c='green',clip_on=False,marker='<')
cb.ax.add_patch(mpl.patches.Rectangle((0,0), 10, -np.log10(significance_threshold),color='cyan', hatch='///',fill=False, snap=True))    
cb.ax.text(37,-np.log10(significance_threshold),"Significance\n" + r"$-log_{10}(0.05)$",va="center",clip_on=False)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you formulate your exact question with some more detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to play around this by using the minor ticks like so:

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
pvalues=np.array([[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],[0.03225688,np.nan,np.nan],[0.9160038 , 0.3538501 ,np.nan]])
labels=[0,1,2]
significance_threshold=0.05
plt.imshow(-np.log10(pvalues),cmap='YlOrRd_r',vmin=0,vmax=10)
plt.xticks(labels)
plt.yticks(labels)
plt.title(r'$-log_{10}(pvalues)$')
#hashing cells of non significant pvalues
for i in labels:
    for j in labels:
        if(i>j):
            if(pvalues[i,j]>0.05):
                plt.gca().add_patch(mpl.patches.Rectangle((j-.5, i-.5), 1, 1,color='cyan', hatch='///',fill=False, snap=True))

cb=plt.colorbar()
cb.ax.add_patch(mpl.patches.Rectangle((0,0), 10, -np.log10(significance_threshold),color='cyan', hatch='///',fill=False, snap=True))    
cb.ax.minorticks_on()
cb.ax.yaxis.set_ticks([-np.log10(significance_threshold)],minor=True)
cb.ax.set_yticklabels(["Significance\n" + r"$-log_{10}(0.05)$"], minor=True)
cb.ax.tick_params(axis='y', which='minor', length=5, width=2, direction='inout',pad=20,color='green')
for i in cb.ax.yaxis.get_ticklines(minor=True):
    i.set_marker('<')
    i.set_data(1.1,0)
```

[image: solution]

Answer (score 0):

It is still not very clear what kind of resizing you would like to do, and isn't going as expected.  One thing I noticed, is that when you change the `vmax` of the `imshow`, for some unknown reason also the xlims of the colorbar change.

You can make your transformations independent of the colorbar's xlims by using the [y-axis transform](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_yaxis_transform.html). With that transform, x-positions are calculated in ["axis coordinates](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html)", going from 0 at the left side of the bar to 1 at the right. And the y-values are in "data coordinates" (the ones shown by the ticks). So, you could create the rectangle with a width of 1 in axis coordinates. And also place the x of the text in axis coordinates, and the y in data coordinates.

The code below shows the changes incorporating the y-axis transform. As an example, `vmax` is set to 15.

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

pvalues = np.array([[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], [0.03225688, np.nan, np.nan], [0.9160038, 0.3538501, np.nan]])
labels = [0, 1, 2]
significance_threshold = 0.05
plt.imshow(-np.log10(pvalues), cmap='YlOrRd_r', vmin=0, vmax=15)
plt.xticks(labels)
plt.yticks(labels)
plt.title(r'$-log_{10}(pvalues)$')

for i in labels:
    for j in labels:
        if (i > j):
            if (pvalues[i, j] > 0.05):
                plt.gca().add_patch(
                    mpl.patches.Rectangle((j - .5, i - .5), 1, 1, color='cyan', hatch='///', fill=False, snap=True))

cb = plt.colorbar()
cb.ax.scatter([3.1], [-np.log10(significance_threshold)], c='green', marker='<',
              clip_on=False, transform=cb.ax.get_yaxis_transform())
cb.ax.add_patch(
    mpl.patches.Rectangle((0, 0), 1, -np.log10(significance_threshold), color='cyan', hatch='///', fill=False,
                          snap=True, transform=cb.ax.get_yaxis_transform()))
cb.ax.text(3.7, -np.log10(significance_threshold), "Significance\n" + r"$-log_{10}(0.05)$",
           ha="left", va="center", clip_on=False, transform=cb.ax.get_yaxis_transform())
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

At the left the original code (but with `vmax=15`), at the right the code with the y-axis transform:

[image: comparison plot]